# webdriverio Set getText string to variable

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumberjs, webdriver-io

I'm currently trying to instantiate a variable with the contents of the getText method using webdriverio.

```
  a = String(browser.getText('.field_notice'));
```

When I attempt to print the variable this is the output:

> [object Object]

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`browser.getText()` is an asynchronous call so you will need to provide a callback to instantiate your variable. Try this :

```
browser
    .getText('.field_notice').then(function(text) {
        a = text;
    });
```

A similar example can be found on the Webdriverio Developer Guide : http://webdriver.io/guide.html

Also, there is no need to convert the variable to a string since this method returns a string. See https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/lib/commands/getText.js

Answer (score -1):

Please use code something like below,

String textValue=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("")).getText();

By.cssSelector("") is to find elements, you can use id or name or css based on the element defined in your page

Comment: The question is about WebdriverIO not selenium-webdriver