# Array not updating

Tags: javascript, automation, nightwatch.js

I am doing some browser automation and starting getting into javascript very recently. At the moment I am very puzzled with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  main_page(browser) {
    var pos;
    var tmp = []; //A

    browser
      .url(myUrl)
      .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
      .assert.elementPresent('#id > ul > li:nth-child(1)')

      for (var i = 1 ; i <= 6; i+=1){
        browser.getText(`#id > ul > li:nth-child(${i})`, function(result){
              pos = result.value.substr(-1) //B
              tmp.push(pos)                 
            })
      }

      tmp.forEach(function(element) { //C
        console.log(element);
      });

      ...

      browser.end();
  },
}
```

I am trying to push `pos` into my array `tmp` so that I can use that to do something later.

What I can't understand is why isn't my array at `A` being updated by my code at `B`. My forEach at `C` doesn't log anything. Can someone help me understand what is happening or explain how to properly do it?

Any input is welcome, thank you.

Comment: `browser` is an async process. Put the `forEach` inside the callback after the `push`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353541/webdriverio-set-gettext-string-to-variable) might actually be what you are looking for.

browser.getText returns a promise, so you should do something like this

```
   browser.getText(`#id > ul > li:nth-child(${i})`).then(function(result){
          pos = result.value.substr(-1) //B
          tmp.push(pos)                 
        })
```

Promises are basically used with asynchronous data. Check out this https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises to know more about promises.